# Cannot open Network tab in firefox developer tools

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

If I go to the firefox developer tools options and check the network tab it does not shows up. The others tabs works well.

How do I open the network tab?

Firefox version: 52.9.0

Edit: the style editor tab also does not shows up

[image: screenshot of the developer tools options]

Comment: Make sure the tool is enabled.  Open the developer tools and go to the preferences page (the gear icon at the top right of the tools).  There you'll see a list of tools -- make sure the network tool's radio button is clicked.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean by "if I go to the firefox developer tools options and check the network tab" : if I check the option for network or style editor, the tabs doesn't open. It works for the others tools.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to clarify things

Comment: You should install the [latest ESR release 60](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) first. Maybe that fixes your problem already.

Comment: @SebastianZartner yep that did the trick. Don't know why it wasn't updating by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgraded to the lastest ESR release : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/